# Angular Material Selection List - set checked columns in template

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a material selection list:

```
<mat-selection-list #pickedCols [(ngModel)]="selectedColumns" (ngModelChange)="onPickColumns($event)">
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let colVal of availableColumns" 
    [selected]="????" <!-- Here i've tried for example selectedColumns.indexOf(colVal) > 0 which doesnt work either -->
    [value]="colVal">{{colVal}}</mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

I want to set the [selected] attribute to true or false depending on whether the string value tied to the Mat-list-option is available in the `selectedColumns` list. Im not sure how I can determine that the options should be checked or not.

in the `ngOnInit` i get the columns as a list of strings:

```
ngOnInit() {
   cols = getColsFromLocalStorage() // ["a", "b", "c"];
   this.selectedColumns = cols // doesnt work
}

onPickColumns(elements: string[]){
  updateColsInLocalStorage(elements);
}
```

I feel like im missing something really basic..

Comment: Check material example I'm sure it would be helpful: https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview#list-selection

Comment: Have you tried inside `[selected]` to use the condition `selectedColumns.includes(colVal)`? This condition should return true if inside selectedColumns array there's a value equal to `colVal`. Be sure that both arrays are typeof string and remember that this condition is case sensitive so you might use "string.toLowerCase()" if values are different from each other.

Comment: @ShayD i've looked but i cant find anything about programmatically checking/setting the value of the checkbox no

Comment: @PietroLungarini I tried that too, doesnt work unfortunately..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to bind `selected`. It's set by default if the value is available in the list.

```
selectedColumns = ['a','b']
availableColumns = ['a','b','c','d']
//This will auto select options 'a', 'b' for you
```

Comment: You're right, it does work without setting that argument.

Comment: it baked in the code here: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/c8b6730a6674844777329f504b6953ee5ee07c61/src/material/list/list-option.ts#L191